# How do I build from the trunk of the jsoup github project?

Tags: github, jsoup

I've realised that the java project I'm working on is affected by this bug: [jsoup Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/jsoup/browse_thread/thread/6fcec982bae3d960)

I don't think this sort of question is really suitable for posting in the group discussion and I don't really want to sit and wait for the next release so could somebody be kind enough to explain what implementing this fix ASAP would entail? How does one build from the trunk of the project?

Just to be clear, I would be looking to end up with a patched version of the jsoup .jar for inclusion in my project.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1):

The reply I got from  on [#git IRC](http://irc://irc.freenode.net/git):

> [jsoup github download link](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/)
>
> You can either use git to archive the repository, or use github's download functionality. After which you will need to compile the jar from the source there. If you choose to use github, when you click download pick either of the .tar.gz or .zip buttons next to "Branch: master"

Lesson learnt: Try IRC first!